# Plot points from JSON file and apply a 3D object into them with webgl2 and javascript

Tags: javascript, webgl2

Its my first time here. How can I import some points from .json type file with known coordinates using vanilla webgl2 and JS? Also if it can be plotted, how a 3D object could be applied in to those points?

the IrisCG.json file contains something like this

```
{
 "values": [
        {
            "x": -2.6841256259695374,
            "y": 0.31939724658510077,
            "z": -0.027914827589413993,
            "class": 0
        },
        {
            "x": 0.6416690842580771,
            "y": -0.41824687156867907,
            "z": 0.041076090823955816,
            "class": 1
        },
        {
            "x": 1.7643457170444288,
            "y": 0.07885885451847563,
            "z": 0.13048163128784818,
            "class": 2
        }
   ]
}
```

the 3D object (its a cube) originally in .obj and I converted it to .js file

```
var  cubeObjStr = `
o Cube.001
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vn -0.5774 0.5774 -0.5774
vn 0.5774 0.5774 0.5774
vn 0.5774 0.5774 -0.5774
vn -0.5774 -0.5774 0.5774
vn 0.5774 -0.5774 0.5774
vn -0.5774 0.5774 0.5774
vn -0.5774 -0.5774 -0.5774
vn 0.5774 -0.5774 -0.5774
usemtl Material.001
s 1
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f 2/2/2 4/4/4 5/5/5
f 6/6/6 7/7/7 4/8/4
f 8/9/8 4/10/4 7/11/7
f 3/3/3 5/5/5 8/9/8
f 1/12/1 8/9/8 7/7/7
f 1/1/1 6/13/6 2/2/2
f 2/2/2 6/14/6 4/4/4
f 6/6/6 1/12/1 7/7/7
f 8/9/8 5/5/5 4/10/4
f 3/3/3 2/2/2 5/5/5
f 1/12/1 3/3/3 8/9/8
`;
```

using [webgl-obj-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webgl-obj-loader) to load the 3D object

```
function setCubeMesh(){
    // Load mesh using the webgl-obj-loader library----------------------------------------
    mesh = new OBJ.Mesh(cubeObjStr);
    OBJ.initMeshBuffers(gl, mesh);
}
```

also here is an idea of a function to load those points

```
var get_json = function(url, func) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false); // if true == asynchronous...
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
            //the file is loaded. Parse it as JSON and launch function
            func(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));
        }
    };
    //send the request
    xmlHttp.send();
}

async function init(){
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var page = path.split("/").pop();
    var baseDir = window.location.href.replace(page, '');
    
    //Load scatter plot dataset from the json
    var dataset; 
    await this.get_json(baseDir+"/irisCG.json", function(jsonFile){
        dataset = jsonFile.values;
    });
    
    //Access fields of the dataset
    for(var i=0;i<3;++i){
        var Point = dataset[i];
        var xPoint = Point[i].x;
        var yPoint = Point[i].y;
        var zPoint = Point[i].z;
        var classPoint = Point[i].class;
    }
}
```

Sorry if it is confusing, I scrap some codes here and there and just only able to grasp the idea without being able to write more complete code.

Comment: At best you're asking for [a tutorial on WebGL2](https://webgl2fundamentals.org) and at worst you're asking way too ambiguous a question. There are a million ways you could draw 3d points.

Comment: I realize that. What I have in mind is the point coordinates maybe could act as the center coordinates of a 3D object (different points could put the 3D mesh in different coordinates). Anyhow, can I ask for an example for drawing 3D points? or should I open other question separately?

Comment: There are examples on the site I linked above.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks